# Moving on X Y axis based on rotation

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to make the character move based on their angle of rotation, however it moves like it is strafing right.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

lilman.rotation = 0
var personRotation:Number = lilman.rotation * (Math.PI / 180)

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, function(e:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(e.keyCode==65)
    {
        lilman.rotation -= 5
    }
    else if(e.keyCode==68)
    {
        lilman.rotation += 5
    }
})

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function()
{
    personRotation = lilman.rotation * (Math.PI / 180)

    lilman.x += Math.cos(personRotation)*5
    lilman.y += Math.sin(personRotation)*5

    trace(Math.cos(personRotation) +", "+ Math.sin(personRotation) +", "+ personRotation +", "+ lilman.rotation)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code. It's 100% fine.

To solve the strafing issue you need to edit the MovieClip object's own  rotation. 
 Assuming your MC is facing upwards (north), make it face right (east) as origin of `0` degrees.

1) Right-click the MC and choose **edit**.

2) In Edit mode... Select everything and (a) rotate it 90 degrees to the right, (b) align the (was previously) bottom to the point `+`. Test if it works as expected

[image]

Comment: I'm using radians, fixed a couple of things I did wrong and now it's always moving as if I'm strafing right even though I haven't made that possible yet.

Comment: Use the [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52249332/edit) link to update your question with any useful info or testable sample code. Three lines of code is not enough to know what else is going on. PS: Ignore my option-B code in the enterframe (looking at it again, that just gives diagonal motion)